# Encoding messed up when using CL_HTTP_CLIENT

Tags: http, request, encode, abap

I make a http request in ABAP like this:

```abap
    CALL METHOD cl_http_client=>create_by_url
      EXPORTING
        URL    = url
      IMPORTING
        client = client.

    client->request->set_header_field(
      name  = 'Content-Type'
      value = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    ).

    client->send(
      EXCEPTIONS
        http_communication_failure = 1
        http_invalid_state         = 2
        http_processing_failed     = 3
        http_invalid_timeout       = 4
        OTHERS                     = 5
    ).

    CHECK sy-subrc = 0.

    client->receive(
      EXCEPTIONS
        http_communication_failure = 1
        http_invalid_state         = 2
        http_processing_failed     = 3
        OTHERS                     = 4
    ).

    string_response = client->response->get_cdata( ).
```

`string_response` is not encoding correctly, the data should be for example `"{"CompanyName": "Uberlândia"}"`, but I'm getting `"{"CompanyName": "UberlÃ¢ndia"}"`, even when I pass **'application/json; charset=utf-8'** on request header `'Content-Type'`

Comment: Maybe: the response could be UTF-8 but not mentioned in the response, so you'd have to use `get_data` instead of `get_cdata`, into a XSTRING variable, then decode its UTF-8 value into character variable using `string_response = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_from( xstring )` (default conversion is UTF-8).

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Even whether I'm passing 'application/json; charset=utf-8' on client response header 'Content-Type'. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the response is encoded in `UTF-8` but not mentioned in the HTTP response.

So you'd have to use `get_data` instead of `get_cdata`, into a variable of type `XSTRING` (string of bytes), then decode its `UTF-8` value into a variable of type `STRING` (string of characters).

```
DATA: xstring_response TYPE xstring,
      string_response  TYPE string.

" Get response as a string of bytes
xstring_response = client->response->get_data( ).

" Assume response is UTF-8 text, so decode it
" (UTF-8 is the default parameter value of method convert_from)
string_response = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_from( xstring_response ).
```